# Iterate Items in node and show them as divs like in React

Tags: node.js

So I'm trying to build an Invoice with Node and I want to iterate some values on it in my template, but I get an error, and I remembered that you can do that outside React. So how to do it, to print all the list with for example 4-5 items?

Here is the template:

```
const content = `
<div>
  ${items.map((item, index) => {
    <p>{item.name}</p>
  })
<div>
`
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        const items = [{name:"A"} , {name:"B"}];
    
        const Content = ()=>{
        return(
        <div>
          ${items.map((item, index) => {
            <p>{item.name}</p>
          })
        <div>
        )

        <Content />
```